# XSL unique value key

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**Goal**

(XSLT 1.0). My goal is to take a set of elements, S, and produce another set, T, where T contains the unique elements in S. And to do so as efficiently as possible. (Note: I don't have to create a variable containing the set, or anything like that. I just need to loop over the elements that are unique).

**Example Input and Key**

```
<!-- My actual input consists of a bunch of <Result> elements -->
<AllMyResults>
<Result>
<someElement>value</state>
<otherElement>value 2</state>
<subject>Get unique subjects!</state>
</Result>
</AllMyResults>

<xsl:key name="SubjectKey" match="AllMyResults/Result" use="subject"/>
```

I think the above works, but when I go to use my key, it is incredibly slow. Below is the code for how I use my key.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Result[count(. | key('SubjectKey', subject)[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:sort select="subject" />
            <!-- Do something with the unique subject value -->
    <xsl:value-of select="subject" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Additional Info**

I believe I am doing this wrong because it slowed down my XSL considerably. As some additional info, the  code shown above is in a separate XSL file from my main XSL file. From the main XSL, I am calling a template that contains the xsl:key and the for-each shown above. The input to this template is an xsl:param containing my node-set (similar to the example input shown above).

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a recommended solution.

Comment: Performance should be measure against some reference wich is absent in this case. Is it slower than what? Is it slower than a stylesheet wich isn't performing the distinction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try substituting**

```
count(. | key('SubjectKey', subject)[1]) = 1
```

**with**:

```
generate-id() = generate-id(key('SubjectKey', subject)[1])
```

In some XSLT processors the latter is much faster.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. I noticed in another thread on this forum, you used something like key('SubjectKey', '.')  ... is using the dot character the same as using the exact name "subject"?

Comment: @KyleM: No, `.` means the current node (and in this case the string value of the current node is used as the key value), and `subject` means all children elements named `subject` -- and in this case the string value of any `subject` child is used as a key value.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason from the information given why the code should be slow. It might be worth seeing if the slowness is something that happens on all XSLT processors, or if it's peculiar to one.