# unique elements with XSL generate-key()

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

First of all thank you to everyone who replied in [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326242/xsl-unique-value-key). In the interest of avoiding confusion I am posting similar information here, but questions updated accordingly.

My problem is that my xsl for-each shown below never gets executed, indicating that there is nothing in the result set. However, I cannot figure out why. Further description below.

**Input structure**

```
<AllMyResults>
<Result>
<someElement>value</state>
<otherElement>value 2</state>
<subject>Get unique subjects!</state>
</Result>
</AllMyResults>
```

At the top of my XSL file I have the key statement

```
<xsl:key name="SubjectKey" match="All_Results/Result" use="subject"/>
```

**[2]** The meat of my XSL file, which uses a different input structure:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$ResultSet/subject[
                         generate-id()
                          = generate-id(key('SubjectKey', 'subject')[1])
                      ]">
... this point is never reached ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Input structure used by [2] above**
The input structure is just a list of  elements.

What am I missing here? I used a debugger to determine that the for-each was never executed, which indicates that the set generated by the expression `$ResultSet/subject[generate-id() = generate-id(key('SubjectKey', 'subject')[1])]` was the empty set. But why?

**Additional Info**

$ResultSet is a node set. It was a parameter passed in to the template. According to my debugger, the "key" statement gets executed the appropriate amount of times -- once per time a "subject" shows up in my input file. According to what I've read about generate-id(), with no params, it operates on the current node. Instead of `$ResultSet/subject` I've also tried all sorts of variations. (`$ResultSet/*/subject`, `$ResultSet/*`, etc)

Comment: You are matching `Result` elements in key declaration...

Comment: Your XML has an element called AllMyResults but your key definition has All_Results. Almost certainly a typo, but if you make typos in your question, it's hard to trust any of the information you give us.

Comment: You close the <someElement> element with  </state> - to me, this does not seem like valid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that should be `key('SubjectKey', subject)`, not `key('SubjectKey', 'subject')` (note the quotes) and that the predicate should be on `$ResultSet`, not `$ResultSet/subject`:

```
$ResultSet[generate-id() = generate-id(key('SubjectKey', subject)[1])]
```

Comment: So I should be using <xsl:key name="SubjectKey" match="All_Results/Result/subject" use="subject"/> and then what you are suggesting .. ? 99% sure I tried that already, but I'll have another go. (I definitely tried both of your suggestions separately, that is, without the quotes & with only $ResultSet, but haven't tried them at once. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleM — I don't think you need to change the `<xsl:key>`, just the `<xsl:for-each>`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  as the key only needs to know what node it is matching on not the  xpath, which seems to be what you are doing.